# $\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-(6-x))}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}dx$ (Now solved)

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral:
$\require{cancel}$
$$\xcancel{I=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-(6-x))}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3-x)}}dx}$$
and the clue given for solving it is:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$
so,
$$\xcancel{\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-(6-x))}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3-x)}}dx=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9+x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}+\sqrt{\ln(x-3)}}dx=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{ln(x+9)}\left(\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}-\sqrt{\ln(x-3)}\right)}{\ln(3+x)-\ln(x-3)}dx}$$
where shall I go from here (if this is the right approach)?

EDIT
if we take the equation to actually be:
$$I=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-(6-x))}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}dx$$
this removes any problems involving $\ln(0)$ as pointed out by users below

If we now use the same method as I outlined above we obtain:
$$\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-(6-x))}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}dx=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}{\sqrt{ln(3+x)}+\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}dx$$
and we can see that the bottom of the fraction is the same on the left and the right, so my first idea would be to add the two sides, giving:
$$2I=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}+\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}+\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}dx=\int_2^41dx=2$$
$$\therefore I=1$$

Comment: There is a problem with the region of integration: when $x>3$, $\ln(3-x)$ is not defined. Should it be $\ln(3+x)$?

Comment: if I define $x\in C$ (for complex)

Comment: Even for $x\in\mathbb C$ you have $\ln(0)$ when $x=3$ which is not defined.

Comment: It is definitely $\ln(3-x)$ https://cgmcwhor.expressions.syr.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Challenge-Integrals.pdf

Comment: Check my previous comment, it shows the source

Comment: I strongly suspect that is a typo in the source.

Comment: It is possible yes. I will edit the question soon and retry my answer

Comment: I think it should be $$I=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-(6-x))}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}dx$$ You get the answer to be $1$

Comment: It would get rid of the problems with ln(0), although the original integral I said does give a convergent complex answer

Comment: @Zacky +1, it works fine now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the integral in the title is not the same as an integral given in an edit.

Comment: I’d rather have this question closed as solved if that is possible

Comment: For a moment I thought I have seen this integral in one of the Putnam papers

Comment: Yes I think it is a modified Putnam integral

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the integral in the title is different from that in the main text

Comment: They are exactly the same except the first two lines, which was to clarify to people originally answering the question that there was a typo in the source